# Determine all triples $(m,n,p)$ of positive rational numbers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, rational-numbers

Determine all triples $(m,n,p)$ of positive rational numbers such that the numbers $m+\frac{1}{np}, n+\frac{1}{pm}, p+\frac{1}{mn}$ are integers.

I have no idea how to go about. Please help.

Comment: $m+\frac{1}{n}p$ or $m+\frac{1}{np}$?

Comment: The latter one.

Comment: @Yellow, could we speak in chat? https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88182/room-for-haran-and-yellow

Comment: @Yellow are you online?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, by multiplying, we can see that $\frac{(mnp+1)^3}{(mnp)^2}$ is an integer. Consider $mnp = \frac{X}{Y}$, where $\gcd(X,Y)=1$. Then, you can see that $X=Y=1$. This gives you $mnp=1$. Replace $m=\frac{w}{x}$, $n=\frac{y}{z}$, $p=\frac{xz}{wy}$, we can see using the three statements with divisibility solving that the only solutions are $(1,1,1)$ , $(2,1,\frac{1}{2})$ and $(4,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2})$, and all its symmetric permutations.

The statements we get are $x \mid 2w$, $z \mid 2y$ and $wy \mid 2xz$. You can take casework to solve these.

Comment: @Yellow can we speak in private chat?

Comment: To add, this problem is from 2006 Balkan Mathematical Olympiad, proposed by Valentin Vornicu, and the solution outlined above, as far as I remember, goes back to Gabriel Dospinescu (aka harazi in AoPS forums).

Comment: Haran, in nowhere I wrote, I did say it is not yours. I said this outline is quite old, goes back to Harazi.

Comment: See AoPS (www.mathlinks.ro) forums, he's a member there, and had many questions in Romanian and USAMO olympiads. In fact, if you are into olympiad mathematics, I highly recommend that you get an account from there, it has a rich collection of many olympiad problems from all across the world.

Comment: I already have an account Aaron. Thanks for the recommendation though!